# Multiple search template with separate stylesheets

Tags: custom-post-types, search, page-template, css

I'm building a site which needs to have two search bars and two search results templates. One  of the search bars is for regular posts, and the other is for a custom post type.

I need the two search results pages to be styled completely differently, so I have set up two templates to display results. One is the standard `search.php` that detects if the post type is a custom one, and displays it on a template named `new-index.php`

Im trying to attach different style sheets to the different pages using the following code:

```
<?php
if ( is_page_template('new-index.php')) { ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/home.css" />
<?php } ?>
```

which dosen't work, but if i use:

```
<?php
if ( is_search()) { ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/gallery.css" />
<?php } ?>
```

it works fine but it gives both the templates the same style sheet, I understand why its happening, but cannot figure out a way around it, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used `is_page_template()` but I have had good luck with `is_page('new_search')` regardless of which conditional you use some things to check.

Is the `is_page_template('new-index.php')` working. you may test this by doing something like:

```
if ( is_page_template('new-index.php')) { wp_die('new search page');}
```

You should also use [`wp_register_style`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style) and [`wp_enqueue_style`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style)  in your `functions.php` hooking in the the `wp_head` which you should have better luck with.

Comment: is_page won't target it and the wp_die test didn't work! I haven't used wp_register_style before, I usually am able to link style sheets to different pages this way. is_search() is still the only one that affects it!

Comment: If the `wp_die()` didn't work then something is either wrong with the template name or how you are registering/displaying the custom search page. Could you provide more code or a link? Also your method works but `wp_register_style` is the more standard (WordPress) way to do it.